# How do you cut a gem

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a Nightstone and a simple grinder, but can't for the life of me figure out how to cut a gem in WoW. What's the right way to do it once you have jewel crafting 300+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cut gems, you open your Skills interface and choose the Professions tab.

[image]

Click on the Jewelcrafting icon and it will open another interface containing a list of the gems you can cut.  Select one and click on the Create button.

However as Jared says, you can't cut Nightstones until you've reached a skill level of 425.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to make nightstone gems until you are at least 425 skill in jewel crafting.

Ref: [Nightstone gems](http://www.wowhead.com/item=52180#reagent-for)